# Floated:right li element is breaking in the ie7 navigation

Tags: css, browser, internet-explorer-7

This the link http://jsfiddle.net/a6K3f/1/.

I need to have one link in right aligned in the navigation menu. Below code is fine in all major browser except in ie7. Right aligned 'Link4' is breaking down. I know it works if i add floated:right li as first li in ul. But i cannt add as first li. Becasue i have written pseduo classes first-child for that.

I tried many trials but not yet resolved. Can anybody please help in my concern issue. Thanks

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
    <li>Link3</li>
    <li class="f-Right">Link4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
*display:inline;
    zoom: 1;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 1px;
    padding: 3px
}
.f-Right {
    float: right
}
```

Comment: Tragically, IE7 can not pull up jsFiddle correctly...

Comment: Oh. yes. How can i share that page? Anyhow you can understand if you see the code once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

please `write` `*float:left;` and `remove`

```
*display:inline;
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6K3f/2/)**

**css**

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    *float:left; /* <--hack for IE **/
    zoom: 1;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 1px;
    padding: 3px
}
.f-Right {
    float: right
}
```

Comment: Hey you solved the issue very simply. Its working well now in all my required browsers even in ie7. I didnt try like this. Thanks for spending time and nice solution.